# Strange use of 'и': для этого и делается

Tags: грамматика, перевод, узус

I was listening at Navalny's phone call and at some point he says:

> ровно для этого и делается доклад

It is supposed to translate to:

> this is exactly what the report is for

What I understand so far:

> ровно для этого = this is exactly (exactly for this)

> делается доклад = report is made

So really, I don't understand the meaning of the connector **и**.

Comment: There are similar uses of и, for example "так и сделаем" = "ok, let's do just that". With context being that there isn't a better option. I think there are very specific contexts where this usage of и happens. так и / для того и / потому и / там и etc

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov I believe actually that your comment is a valid answer, it seems to me it would be just awesome if you'll convert it.

Comment: @shabunc I don't feel like I can list all the (most  of the) possible contexts and I am not satisfied with the explanation of the exact change in meaning

Comment: I think we may sometimes use "and" in a similar way in English. Couldn't we translate his words as: "And that is basically why you make a report."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "и" in Russian apart from its main function also serves as - very roughly - as a counterpart of English so, like in phrase "so what"? - this is translated like "и что"? The "и" add expressiveness and the whole phrase get a slightly different meaning.

Let's examine one of examples provided by @yaroslav-fyodorov, extending them for context.

"Поэтому и надо ложиться в одно и то же время" and "Поэтому надо ложиться в одно и то же время". While both phrases can be translated as "That's why / here's why you need to go to sleep at the same time". However, the second sentence is a mere statement of fact, while the first one is more emotional, with emphasis on "that's why". Imagine that actual situation was something like:

> Ты такой дёрганый, потому что на этой неделе спишь нерегулярно. Потому и надо ложиться в одно и то же время!

In this context without "и" second sentence - completely grammatical and valid in this context as well - will still sound slightly off.

The same happens in the sentence that raised your question. When why says, "ровно для этого и делается доклад" it's like putting more emotion and emphasise more that's why in phrase "**that's why** this report is made".

Comment: Вот о таком подробном ответе я и говорил

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov хороший пример! Это специально? )

Comment: @Curiosity разумеется

Comment: Thanks everybody for your explanations!